# Should this coding challenge posted on SO be moved to PPCG?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

This is the question I'm talking about: [Twitter image encoding challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891643/twitter-image-encoding-challenge)

It was already closed as not constructive two years after the question was posted, but now we have a site that is all about this kind of question, specifically the [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf SE (beta)](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com). Should the question be moved there?

Answer (score 4):

Questions can only be migrated if they have been asked within the past 60 days.  This post *cannot* be migrated.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. (The question would be much better fitted if it's migrated but oh well.)

Answer (score 4):

There have been instances where [old posts](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/706799/revisions) have been moved [to another site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/48973/revisions) long after they were closed on the original site.  It is something that only SE employes can do (mods can't) and is done on a case by case basis.

In my opinion, this would be a good candidate to suggest such a migration.

However, there is a gotcha in this *because* of its popularity.

The popularity of the question on Stack Overflow has many [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/891643?lq=1) on site, many more likely outside of Stack Exchange) that would go dead when the migrated post eventually gets deleted (30 days after migration - its one of the roomba scripts - during that time it is a redirect instead.

To do this migration semi-properly, Stack exchange would need to have code for a permeant redirect in place for questions that have a sufficient amount of views or links prior to the migration.

Comment: I'm surprised they don't have redirects for migrated questions.  Huh.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom hmm... I might just be looking at things wrong with certain posts, maybe they do.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom poking/asking around, it seems like there was a bug at one time dealing with redirects and migrations that appears to have gotten fixed.